# Multi-threading using R dbGetQuery function with JDBC driver

Tags: r, multithreading, jdbc

Is there a way to force multi-threading  when using R dbGetQuery  function to read a table from a JDBC connection? I am wondering if this could increase reading speed.

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="C:/driver_JDBC/ojdbc6.jar")
con <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver,username =  "myusername", password =   "mypassword ")
TABLE <- dbGetQuery(conn_jdbc, "SELECT * FROM my_table")
```

Comment: Probably not, although JDBC drivers are theoretically thread-safe, the way they work makes linear retrieval of data a necessity. Adding multi-threading in the mix would probably only add overhead and possibly risk running into race conditions or other concurrency issues.